# Dynamic SQL in SAP HANA Stored Procedures

Tags: dynamic-sql, hana

I want to create a stored procedure in HANA, which does the following :

- Accepts IN parameter of Table type.
- Accepts another IN parameter of Varchar type.
- Filters some rows from a existing table based on column values of first input parameter.
- Tries to sort (ORDER BY) rows based on criteria given by second input parameter.

Here is the stored procedure that I want to create

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DEMO_PROD_EXAMPLE_DYNAMIC(IN TEMPLIST PRODLISTTYPE,IN ORDERSTRING VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN
OUTVAR = SELECT * FROM DEMO_PRODS WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM :TEMPLIST);

SELECT * FROM :OUTVAR ORDER BY :ORDERSTRING DESC;

END;
```

I am facing the following hurdle :

- In the above procedure, ordering does not happen at all! If I hardcode the column name, like `SELECT * FROM :OUTVAR ORDER BY ID DESC;` it works.
- If I try to create a dynamic SQL query like `SELECT * FROM'|| :OUTVAR||' ORDER BY '||:ORDERSTRING||'DESC';` I get an exception

  > not allowed to use varchar and table type with concatenation operator.

How do I sort the resultset based on a dynamic condition (column name/s passed to procedure) in HANA.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://uacp2.hana.ondemand.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.01/en-US/093c4fd307064f838cb582555c187b9e.html) to execute a dynamic SQL statement:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NAME FROM DEMO_PRODS ' || :ORDERSTRING || ' DESC';
```

However, with dynamic SQL you cannot use table typed variables to select from. So you need to find another solution for `SELECT * FROM DEMO_PRODS WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM :TEMPLIST);`. Using a [global temporary table](http://help-legacy.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d58a5f75191014b2fe92141b7df228/content.htm) is one:

```sql
INSERT INTO TEMPORARY_TABLE (SELECT * FROM DEMO_PRODS WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM :TEMPLIST);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NAME FROM TEMPORARY_TABLE ' || :ORDERSTRING || ' DESC';
```

Comment: Thanks! Creating a global temporary table works! But it might not be an efficient/clean solution. Is there any other alternative which avoids creating global/local temp tables and involves only local variables in a procedure?

Comment: Also would not using global/local temporary tables too much lead to read/write conflicts when multiple users are accessing the DB?

Comment: @ShubhaLakshmi: It's definitely a perfect solution, but Dynamic SQL has limitations. One is that you cannot use table type variables. However, there should be issues with multiple users. In the documentation I linked, you can find `Makes the table definition globally available while data is visible only to the current session.` If you create the table with the option `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, it gets automatically truncated if you commit the transaction.
In general, I'd try to avoid Dynamic SQL at all and think for another solution. If possible, use XS and generate the query there.